# How can I change the skin color of a human body image?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have an image of a human body showing skin. How can I change the color of the skin assuming I have another skin color and assuming I have a mask of the exposed skin in the body image ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried?  Please show code and your input images and new color.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV. I am not sure how robust it is.

Basically, we get the average color of the face. The get the difference color (in each channel) between that and the desired color. Then we add the difference to the input image. Then we use the mask to combine the original and new images.

Input:

[image]

Facemask:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# specify desired bgr color for new face and make into array
desired_color = (180, 128, 200)
desired_color = np.asarray(desired_color, dtype=np.float64)

# create swatch
swatch = np.full((200,200,3), desired_color, dtype=np.uint8)

# read image
img = cv2.imread("zelda1.jpg")

# read face mask as grayscale and threshold to binary
facemask = cv2.imread("zelda1_facemask.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
facemask = cv2.threshold(facemask, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get average bgr color of face
ave_color = cv2.mean(img, mask=facemask)[:3]
print(ave_color)

# compute difference colors and make into an image the same size as input
diff_color = desired_color - ave_color
diff_color = np.full_like(img, diff_color, dtype=np.uint8)

# shift input image color
# cv2.add clips automatically
new_img = cv2.add(img, diff_color)

# antialias mask, convert to float in range 0 to 1 and make 3-channels
facemask = cv2.GaussianBlur(facemask, (0,0), sigmaX=3, sigmaY=3, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
facemask = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(facemask, in_range=(100,150), out_range=(0,1)).astype(np.float32)
facemask = cv2.merge([facemask,facemask,facemask])

# combine img and new_img using mask
result = (img * (1 - facemask) + new_img * facemask)
result = result.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('zelda1_swatch.png', swatch)
cv2.imwrite('zelda1_recolor.png', result)

cv2.imshow('swatch', swatch)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Desired color swatch:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Fred - hopefully, that "pinkfacing" is in concordance with [StackOverflow's Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). ;-)

Comment: @HansHirse Thanks for the link. I did not know about that. But I can change the color to something else if it offends anyone or remove the example. No disrespect was intended and this is a publicly available image (Zelda).

Comment: Sorry how do you get the facemask?

Comment: @George Bora  Sorry, it has been too long. But likely manually traced it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure



#usage
#put this script and the image face.jpg in the same directory /dir
#run these 2 commands inside bash
#cd /dir
#python change_skin_v1.py

#script_name= change_skin_v1.py


#you can change  the 3 parameters: alpha, skincolor_low, skincolor_high


#path file
path_face="./face.jpg"
result_partial="./result_partial.png"
result_final="./result_partial.png"


#blending parameter
alpha = 0.7


# Define lower and uppper limits of what we call "skin color"
skincolor_low=np.array([0,10,60])
skincolor_high=np.array([180,150,255])



#specify desired bgr color (brown) for the new face.
#this value is approximated
desired_color_brg = (2, 70, 140)




# read face
img_main_face = cv2.imread(path_face)



# face.jpg has by default the BGR format, convert BGR to HSV
hsv=cv2.cvtColor(img_main_face,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)




#create the HSV mask
mask=cv2.inRange(hsv,skincolor_low,skincolor_high)



# Change image to brown where we found pink
img_main_face[mask>0]=desired_color_brg
cv2.imwrite(result_partial,img_main_face)




#blending block start

#alpha range for blending is  0-1


# load images for blending
src1 = cv2.imread(result_partial)
src2 = cv2.imread(path_face)

if src1 is None:
    print("Error loading src1")
    exit(-1)
elif src2 is None:
    print("Error loading src2")
    exit(-1)
    
    
# actually  blend_images
result_final = cv2.addWeighted(src1, alpha, src2, 1-alpha, 0.0)
cv2.imwrite('./result_final.png', result_final)

#blending block end
```

[image: Example]