# How can I blur a mask and smooth its edges?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, mediapipe

**I want to change the color of the cheeks of this photo.
I got a mask with sharp edges**
**How can I blur a mask and smooth its edges?**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB54C.png)
[mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pca8e.png)

Comment: Thanks for posting this question! Can you post the code you have so far and explain how you are stuck?

Comment: ok 
this code 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71874524/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-part-of-the-image-without-losing-the-texture-of
problem:
I want to change the color of the cheeks of this photo. I got a mask with sharp edges How can I blur a mask and smooth its edges?

Comment: May I suggest that you do some image processing tutorials? For example, if you work through some of these, you'll soon get the hang of things > https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/

Comment: See how I blur the mask and stretch it to blend the edges of the lips at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71860084/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-lip-that-got-its-landmarks-without-disturbing/71864126#71864126

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Similar questions on this topic of changing make-up  have been asked several times recently. Is this some school project?

Comment: yes project of my university

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# import the necessary packages
import argparse
import cv2
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", type=str, default="pca8e.png",
    help="path to input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# load the image, display it to our screen, and initialize a list of
# kernel sizes (so we can evaluate the relationship between kernel
# size and amount of blurring)
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
cv2.imshow("Original", image)
kernelSizes = [(41,41)]
# loop over the kernel sizes
for (kX, kY) in kernelSizes:
    # apply a "Gaussian" blur to the image
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (kX, kY), 0)
    cv2.imshow("Gaussian ({}, {})".format(kX, kY), blurred)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Try this code to blur the mask image. But I don't know how you're going to use it with your image.

Comment: I just want to blur the mask!!
Not the whole image

Comment: You can use cv2.circle( ) method for detection the specified area and make it blur. and you may use np.where() method to select the pixels where you want blurred values and then replace them.